# Dependency limma not available when installing MKmisc package

Tags: r, windows, package

When installing this package in R 4.2.1

```
install.packages("MKmisc")
```

I have this output

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/blahblah/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘limma’ is not available
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/MKmisc_1.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 769544 bytes (751 KB)
downloaded 751 KB

package ‘MKmisc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

It does not work as we need to download the package `limma` so let's do it

```
install_github("cran/limma")
```

However it gives an error and the `MKmisc` package is still not working

What should I do to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"limma"` can be installed using `BiocManager`.

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("limma")
install.packages("MKmisc")
# * DONE (MKmisc)
# The downloaded source packages are in
#         ‘/tmp/Rtmphwh6rY/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem has been solved.